# Super simple KG to LBS conveter

Tags: python

just got into python, any advice why these simple lines sends me an error?

```
# ---------------- WEIGHT CONVERTER ----------------#

_userWeight = input("Weight [KG]: ")
_userLbs = int(_userWeight) * 2.2
print(int(_userWeight) + "[KG] = " + int(_userLbs) + "[lbs]")
```

Comment: now what error do you get?

Comment: You cannot concatenate str and int. Use f-strings or str.format() method.

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  _userWeight = input("Weight [KG]: ")
  _userLbs = int(_userWeight) * 2.2 
  print(int(_userWeight) , "[KG] = " , int(_userLbs) , "[lbs]")
```

Remove the '+' and use a ','

Output:

> Weight [KG]: 50
>
> 50 [KG] =  110 [lbs]

Comment: Thanks you for the quick solution. so in which cases do I use the + signs when working with strings and other variables?

Comment: only when everythin you print is the same exact data type

Comment: A '+' is basically a concatenate, and you cannot concatenate diff. data types

Answer (score 0):

You cannot concatenate both string and integer data types.

You can however present the values as a string:

```
_userWeight = input("Weight [KG]: ")
_userLbs = int(_userWeight) * 2.2
print(str(_userWeight) + "[KG] = " + str(_userLbs) + "[lbs]")

# 80[KG] = 176.0[lbs]
```

Comment: _mix_ is unclear term in this case

Comment: _You cannot print both strings and integers on a single lin_ this becomes worse with every iteration...

Comment: Well I amended it prior. Is it now tolerable?

Comment: It's not at all about printing. It's about **concatenating** `str` and `int` objects. They can as well try to construct a `str` by concatenating `str` and `int` and bind it to a name and it will fail all the same. e.g. `result = int(_userWeight) + "[KG] = " + int(_userLbs) + "[lbs]"`. And it's completly different story if they need `int()` at all.

Comment: Yeah.. it is absolutely about printing though. That's actually the crux of the question.

Comment: No, the problem and question is about the concatenating. It just happens that they construct the string and print it in one-line. It may well be a return statement in a function.

Comment: 'It may well be' cuts in any number of directions.

Comment: Just look at the other answer by @PSR and you will learn how to print `str` and `int` in one line. Of course `f-string` and `str.format()` are always preferable.

Comment: Can't argue with that.